# How did the non-French pronunciation of Captain Picard's name come about?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes, jean-luc-picard

[*Star Trek: The Next Generation*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation) introduced among its main cast [Captain Jean-Luc Picard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard), explicitly defined as a Frenchman, who was given an accordingly French name.

I grew up watching TNG with the German dubbing, and Picard's name (both first and last) was consistently pronounced with the French pronunciation by himself and anyone else on the show.

When I first watched TNG with the original English audio, I was somewhat surprised the original voices invariably changed the name by simply reading out what the letters "Jean-Luc Picard" could sound like in English, barely approximating the sound in French.

**How did it come to this?**

I simply can't see a reason for it:

- If it was not possible to pronounce anything non-English, then why insist on him being a Frenchman in the first place? (This touches upon other aspects, such as him liking Earl Grey Tea and Shakespeare rather than anything particularly French.)
- I read Patrick Stewart said him doing a French accent would have ended up sounding silly. But then, why wasn't at least a French name picked that would be easier to pronounce for native English speakers, or where the French pronunciation would have been closer to the English one, than especially Picard's first name, "Jean-Luc" (which, despite its shortness, appears to contain as many as three distinct sounds that English native speakers would not be used to)?
- Even so, why was even the effort of acknowledging that the final 'd' in "Picard" would not be audible in French deemed too much? That wouldn't have required a full-fledged "French accent".

Was production too far along so the name couldn't be changed anymore when the problem the actors had with it became apparent? Was the name somehow that uniquely special that there was no option of changing it? What happened there? Are there any interviews or texts that describe the process in those days?

EDIT: As an example, [here](https://youtu.be/Epq6FKF7qWU?t=34) you can hear Dr. Crusher's German voice call the Captain by his given name, and [here](https://youtu.be/HVd-U1sAwvo?t=35) is the same line with the original English voice - the latter sounds pretty much like "John Look" to me, in particular, the 'n' at the end of "Jean" is clearly audible in English instead of the nasal sound. Unfortunately, I cannot find this scene (or any other with his name in it, for that matter) with the French dubbing on YouTube, which would grant an even better comparison (as I can verify locally with other scenes when setting Netflix audio to French).

Comment: It's not a mis-pronunciation. It's how someone that speaks English would pronounce that surname

Comment: I have a delivery here for John Luck Pickard?

Comment: could the question be updated to include examples of the you think the proper pronunciation to be?

Comment: @JackBNimble: Indeed, that's pretty much what it sounds like in the English version of the show.

Comment: @NKCampbell: I was able to find a scene on YouTube with his first name spoken in different language versions and added the links.

Comment: They pronounce his name "Zhon Look Pickard", not "Gene Luke Pickard" as you would expect from the spelling. "J" is typically pronounced "dzh" in English.

Comment: @CJDennis: You're right about Zhon vs. Gene, it could be even worse.

Comment: I am French and honestly, the German version sounds like it was pronounced by the voice of Google Translate. I completely lost focused after that.

Comment: @Taladris: Interesting - do the pronunciations of the name in English and German sound equally distant from what it is actually pronounced like in French to you?

Comment: Flippant answer: maybe he's pronouncing it in perfect French but the universal translator is mangling it into an Anglophone rendition for the sake of the rest of the crew.

Comment: In fact I suppose the Universal Translator makes the French and German dubs just as canonical as the original audio.

Comment: I would be nice if you wrote down the two pronunciations (obviously accent is impossible to capture that way....but we're not talking about French speakers so that's moot).

Comment: There are also things like [Quebecois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French) which is essentially French, but I heard some French don't believe their ears when they hear this ... flavor ... of their language.

Answer (score 22):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard

> Jean-Luc Picard was born to Maurice and Yvette Picard in La Barre, France, on 13 July 2305. As a child, he dreamed of joining Starfleet.[17] **He and the rest of his family speak English, with English accents—the French language having become obscure by the 24th century**, as mentioned in the Next Generation episode "Code of Honor". Picard also has a number of British habits, including the regular consumption of Earl Grey tea, a fondness for Shakespeare, which he performs in holodeck simulations, riding horses with English tack and a knowledge of such British songs with Royal Navy associations as "A British Tar" (Gilbert and Sullivan) and "Heart of Oak". [bolding added]

> Star Trek creator Gene Roddenberry named Picard for one or both of the twin brothers Auguste Piccard and Jean Piccard, 20th-century Swiss scientists.

So while Picard is apparently ethnically French, my understanding is that France and French do not exist in the 24th century as we know them today. So apparently, the English pronunciation of "Picard" has come to dominate, at least in Jean-Luc's portion of the family. And in more than three centuries, it's likely that pronunciations have shifted.

Comment: https://youtu.be/pwODwwgE6rA

Comment: "And in more than three centuries, it's likely that pronunciations have shifted." – As a native German speaker having also learned French in school (and living on the French border), I recently watched a documentary about the Texas German language, and I recently visited Montréal, Canada, and *MAN* can I attest to that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ah, yes, Montréal, where the same person may speak English with French accent and French with English accent (lay tay - the summér)

Comment: The French language may have become "obscure," but Jean-Luc doesn't much like it when [people point that out](http://chakoteya.net/NextGen/104.htm). :-D

Comment: Yes, I've heard by the  24th century, French is only spoken by French, Canadians, Louisianans, Haitians, Guyanese and diplomats.

Comment: Probably due to the English returning the favour in 2066, when, the EU having long crumbled to ruins, William V invaded Normandy, marched on Paris and set up shop there.

Comment: This isn't even unusual today. Plenty of actors in the US have Anglicised their surnames' pronunciation. One example that immediately comes to mind is Melissa Benoist. "Be-noyst", not "ben-wah". It's not mispronounced by people: it's been deliberately anglicised by the family that hold it. Indeed, this is true of my own family surname, though I'm not in the US nor an actor ;) IMO OP needs to open their minds a bit.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I'm aware this is not that unusual today. But in general, Star Trek describes mankind in the 24th century as "enlightened" or "evolved". Intuitively, I'd have assumed this includes an increased awareness of foreign languages, at least to the point that foreign words/names are recognized as such and not automatically read out as if they belonged to one's native language. With that said, I'm well aware that the question whether foreign words and names are actually pronounced (close to) the original way is treated very differently by different cultures on this planet.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I've yet to hear an explanation that maps "society is more enlightened/evolved" (whatever we decide that even means) to "everybody uses centuries-old authentic national pronunciations for names regardless of intermediate societal changes and the increasing globalisation of culture". It really does seem like you're just projecting your own unease with the flexibility of language. Your question's premise is "everybody in the show is _mispronouncing_ the name"; you start off with the assumption that they're wrong unless they do it like you. So you've set yourself up to fail!

Comment: "my understanding is that France and French do not exist in the 24th century as we know them today" - well, he does utter a few French words throughout the run of the series that *are* pronounced pretty much by French pronunciation rules, as it seems ("maman" and "merde" come to my mind, plus the lyrics of "Frère Jacques"). Thus, the language cannot totally have disappeared, though it may be archaic in the eyes of some.

Comment: "And in more than three centuries, it's likely that pronunciations have shifted." - unless the English we hear on the show has shifted away from what is usual today, as well, this point seems irrelevant. Clearly, the universal translator built into our TV sets translates Earth languages on the show for us to *contemporary* versions of the same Earth languages ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I'm sorry, I fail to see where you find "flexibility of language" if the topic is precisely the inflexibility to break out of the pronunciation patterns of a single language. 'Your question's premise is "everybody in the show is mispronouncing the name"' - no, my question's presmise is "If Picard were a Frenchman today, he'd pronounce his name like *this*. Why did the showrunners have him pronounce his name like *that* instead?" Societal changes by the 24th century are a good retroactive explanation to fix the issue in-universe, but as this was never made a ...

Comment: ... plot point, one has to wonder why the character wasn't simply redefined to be of British rather than French origin.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper _"no, my question's presmise is 'If Picard were a Frenchman today, he'd pronounce his name like this'"_ And I already explained that this is not necessarily true. Let's agree to disagree as we're going in circles. But perhaps consider editing your question so that it isn't, throughout, accusatory, assuming that it was "a mistake" or due to "a problem" or that it was "a mispronunciation", just because it's not the way _you'd_ say it.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Thank you, I have edited the wording of some statements in the question. I do not quite agree with your suggestion that this is comparable to the situation where "Plenty of actors in the US have Anglicised their surnames' pronunciation.", because Star Trek's future Earth is described as a "united Earth" rather than a "worldwide USA" and Picard is from France, possibly based (if his quarters weren't on a spaceship) in France, after all. Still, "Picard lives in an English-speaking world and it is ...

Comment: ... customary in 24th century English to apply English pronunciation rules to foreign names and loanwords like it is already the case in <add any contemporary English-speaking country of your preference as an example> now" is actually a fitting answer to this question - which I recommend you post as such.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It's already been shown here that the French language is considered obscure in Picard's time, regardless of which piece of land he grew up on. Just like how the French language isn't commonplace in the USA now. So it's the same situation and I don't think matters need be interpreted as much more complex than that: once you get over the linguistic elitism, it's quite simple. ;)